# TabBarView and BottomNavigationBar to control what displays at body of Scaffold

Tags: flutter

I can't have both **TabBarView** and **BottomNavigationBar** control what displays at the body of my Scaffold. With this code, either TabBarView has control or BottomNavigationBar.

I want to be able to scroll sideways between ALL FOUR pages as well as pick HOME and FAVORITES to control what displays on the screen.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Traveler"),
      bottom: new TabBar(controller: controller, tabs: <Tab>[
        new Tab(text: "NEW"),
        new Tab(text: "HOTELS"),
        new Tab(text: "FOOD"),
        new Tab(text: "FUN"),
      ]),
    ),
    body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Offstage(
          offstage: index != 0,
          child: new TickerMode(
            enabled: index == 0,
            child: new Material(child: new NewPage()),
          ),
        ),
        new Offstage(
          offstage: index != 1,
          child: new TickerMode(
            enabled: index == 1,
            child: new Material(child: new HotelsPage()),
          ),
        ),
        new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
          new NewPage(),
          new HotelsPage(),
          new FoodPage(),
          new FunPage(),
        ]),
      ],
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text("Home"),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: new Text("Favorites"),
          ),
        ]),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tweaked your code a little to achieve what I think you were asking for.
You can switch between the for tabs by just clicking on the tabs or by swiping left or right. Instead of using `Offstages` you can just create a new instance of the required class.

Here is a running example, I hope it helps:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _controller;
  int _index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _index = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Traveler"),
        bottom: new TabBar(controller: _controller, tabs: <Tab>[
          new Tab(text: "NEW"),
          new Tab(text: "HOTELS"),
          new Tab(text: "FOOD"),
          new Tab(text: "FUN"),
        ]),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          new NewPage(_index),
          new HotelsPage(_index),
          new FoodPage(_index),
          new FunPage(_index),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _index,
          onTap: (int _index) {
            setState(() {
              this._index = _index;
            });
          },
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
              title: new Text("Home"),
            ),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
              title: new Text("Favorites"),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  NewPage(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Text('NewPage, index: $index'),
    );
  }
}

class HotelsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  HotelsPage(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Text('HotelsPage, index: $index'),
    );
  }
}

class FoodPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  FoodPage(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Text('FoodPage, index: $index'),
    );
  }
}

class FunPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  FunPage(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Text('FunPage, index: $index'),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have any questions to this, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: please how to use TabBar replace navigation bar at bottom of screen,

Comment: on ```BottomNavigationBarItem``` change title to label. 
title is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use "label" instead, as it allows for an improved text-scaling experience. This feature was deprecated after v1.19.0